# jQuery remove row with matching file name as hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a markup like this

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="file-name" value="file.doc">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Test 1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="file-name" value="file1.docx">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Test 2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="file-name" value="file.pdf">
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="Test 3"></td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
  <a href="#" id="remove">Remove File</a>
```

In that markup you can see I have file name as hidden fields and under the table I have a remove file tag. So the thing is like this when I will click on the remove file then it will remove that entire row(tr tag) inside where the filename 
file.doc is present. So for that I have made my js like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#remove').click(function(e) {
        var FileName = 'file.doc';
        var GetRowVal = $('table#data td #file-name').val();
        if(GetRowVal == FileName ) {
          var Parent = $(GetRowVal).parent().remove();
        }
        else {
          console.log(' error');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

But it is not removing the row. So can someone kindly tell me whats the issue here? Any help and suggestions will be really apprecaible. Thanks

Comment: IDs should be unique.

Comment: The attribute `id` has to be unique in the whole DOM, so consider about changing `#file-name` and `id="file-name"` to something like `.file-name` and `class="file-name"`.

Comment: Does $(GetRowVal).parent() point to the correct section of the DOM element? It will never remove the <tr>, since the parent of the <input> is <td>, not <tr>.

Comment: Is the link gone have a dynamic value to what row "filename" its gone delete?

Answer (score 0):

There are duplicate id's in your Html,just correct that issue and try below answer :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#remove').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var FileName = 'file.doc';
        $('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
          if( $(this).val() == FileName )
          {
             $(this).closest('tr').remove();
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code return Array of Jquery Object.
Then function .val() cannot have meaning.

```
$('table#data td #file-name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two probles in this code:

first : Ids are not unique.

second:

```
var GetRowVal = $('table#data td #file-name').val();
```

will hold only value eg. `file.doc`
so you can't later 
remove the object in this line:

```
var Parent = $(GetRowVal).parent().remove();
```

so to repair it first change id to class like here:

```
<input type="hidden" class="file-name" value="file.doc">
```

and later You can modify your code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#remove').click(function(e) {
    var GetRowVal = $(".file-name[value='file.doc']");
      $(GetRowVal).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});
```

[Here jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsty49w8/1/)